# React native FBSDK not linking properly

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using [react-native fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) in my react-native app. I have followed every step carefully, but somehow it seems like the linking has not been done properly.

When I run the project I get the following errors in the debugger console.[image]

I have wrapped my head around this problem for too long but failed to find a solution.

Already tried deleting node_modules, reinstalling all packages, linking etc.

Comment: I am also having this problem, please let me know if you find any solutions and I will do the same. There is a pull request on the repo to restore linking functionality, but I haven't seen a workaround anywhere. https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/349

Comment: No solutions yet. I'm doing the development by commenting that part of the code and removing FBSDK related stuff. :(